# Urn problem for pairs of black balls

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have an urn with $n_1$ white balls and $n_2$ black balls. We draw balls without replacement $n_1+n_2$ times. I would like to have some little clue how to calculate probability of getting $l$ pairs of black balls. For example, if $n_1=1$, $n_2=2$, we have $BBW$, $BWB$,$WBB$ possible results of drawings, $\frac{2}{3}$ is the probability of getting $1$ pair of black balls.

Comment: For larger values of n1 and n2, would you consider the sequence BBBL to contain 1 or 2 pairs?

Comment: I would consider BBBL as containing 2 consecutive pairs of black balls

Comment: But your question is to find the probability of getting the first consecutive pair or what?

Comment: Please correct the phrase "1 consecutive pairs of black balls". Maybe you mean "at least two consecutive black balls"?

Comment: It seems like it is " l as in Large" consecutive pairs, somebody has just edited it.  OP, Am I right?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is right. A particular number of consecutive pairs of black balls

Comment: It seems as if your criteria of "$l$ consecutive pairs of blackballs" is equivalent to "$l+1$ consecutive black balls", so why didn't you use the latter instead?

Comment: I chose to use pairs because it could be the case when 2 pairs are separated by one white ball. For instance BBWBB will lead to two pairs.  Maybe I should delete a word consecutive from my problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\tbinom{n_1+n_2}{n_2}$ equally probable binary sequences. Now we count those with $p$ pairs.

Each pair must have a left-hand member, which we can choose from any of the black balls except the last: $\tbinom{n_2-1}{p}$. This will create $n_2-p$ blocks of black, which we can distribute into the $n_1+1$ slots between and around the white balls: $\tbinom{n_1+1}{n_2-p}$. Thus the number of sequences with exactly $p$ pairs is $\tbinom{n_2-1}{p}\tbinom{n_1+1}{n_2-p}$.

This gives a probability of $\frac{\tbinom{n_2-1}{p}\tbinom{n_1+1}{n_2-p}}{\tbinom{n_1+n_2}{n_2}}$.

Comment: Very good logic, I enumerated it for a few scenarios but could not crack it just like yours. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for comment, Andrew. What will happen if we have the number of slots around white balls $n_{1}+1$ less or equal than the number of blocks of black $n_{2}-p$?

Comment: For integers $0<x<y$, by convention $\tbinom{x}{y}=0$. So if $n_1+1<n_2-p$, then $\tbinom{n_1+1}{n_2-p}=0$ by definition, and the probability is zero. This is also the result if $p>n_2$.

Comment: Yes, makes the probability of getting the number of pairs less then  $n_{2}-n_{1}-1$ being zero